# API with CURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get a JSON object from a API.
And have already suceeded in getting the result with the curl command like the following.

***curl -X GET -H "X-ZzzzzApi-Access-Token: _______________" https://XXXXX.XXXXXX.com/XXXXXX?id=123456***

If someone tell me how to solve that with PHP, I would be so happy.

In short...I don't know how to connect the API with setting a certain header and a request parameter which I'm adding at the end of the URL.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look into Guzzle http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use it like below in the PHP CURL sample:

```
  $curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://XXXXX.XXXXXX.com/XXXXXX?id=123456",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Authorization: bWpOUTMrcGd3UzYkdZVzRTeDU0QlE9PQ==",
    "x-api-key: bXFFOFRjbUJlWm1Oa3M0MWU1clBQ=="
  ),
));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply! If you know, could you help with this error I 'm facing?  I got this message on my screen "cURL Error #:SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Comment: You need a trusted certificate for your request because of your API which uses an SSL certificate,  I updated my answer and another option added, If do you have a certificate you should instead of `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` you should use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "BuiltinObjectToken-EquifaxSecureCA.crt");`

Comment: Hats off to you! After I added a line like you, the JASON object appeared on my screen. I greatly appreciate your kindness, amiraliio

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). You can seem your api´s header and it create a php curl code automatically.